# Angular4のコンフィグファイルなどについて

Tags: angular4

Angular4を勉強中なのですが、
例えば外部ファイルなどで、個々の設定値などを持たせたい場合、
一般的にはどのようにしているのでしょうか？

アプリ名\src\assets\設定ファイル.json　のような形で用意する感じでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsonでもいいですし、objectをexportするjsファイルでもいいと思います。jsだと当然何らかの処理ができるのでより柔軟に書けます。

**config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  port: 8000 + 80
}
```

**some.js**

```
const config = require('./config.js')
const port = config.port
```

ただconfigファイルはassetじゃない気がするので`assets`フォルダーに置かない方がいいと思います。

Comment: karamarimoさま回答ありがとうございます。さっそく試してみました。値が取れることもかくにんできました。ひとまず、assetではなく、src/app配下に用意して使用することにしました。